# Autogenerated cwl Files for TexStudio seem to be broken

Tags: latex, editor

TexStudio autogenerates .cwl File for every used package. These Files are used for autocompletion, but they seem to be broken.

The autogenerated Files contain commands like the following:

```
\task{arg1}#S
```

These commands then dont work for autocompletion. If i change the contents of the file to the following it works:

```
\task{arg1}#D
```

It seems to me that the autogenerated Files use a wrong placeholder(#S instead of #D). 
Does this have to do something with my setup or is it a problem everyone has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondered the same and did some searching.

This is working as intended. To quote the [TexStudio FAQ](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion)

> **Why does a command not show up in the completion?**
>
> First, check if TXS knows the command at all. Commands that are not
>   known are marked in red by the syntax checker. See How does TXS know
>   about valid commands? for more details. If the command is unknown, the
>   solution is to write a cwl file defining the command and to put the
>   file in the settings directory.
>
> If TXS knows about the command, check if it appears in the all tab of
>   the completer. **Some commands are marked as unusual in the cwl file to
>   keep the completer from overcrowding.** As a result they will only show
>   in the all tab, not in the typical tab. **This is the default for all
>   commands in automatically generated .cwl files**. You are free to change
>   this by editing the corresponding .cwl file.